# Bugs in new design

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

New header and footer changes cools and I am happy to see this new design but there are some bugs in design

> network site and reputation is not align

[image]

> Stackexchange Icon is also hard to visible in first view

[image]

And also few minutes ago site is down can Anybody tell me the reason

[image]

Comment: The display issue has been fixed. Site unavailability was due to a misbehaving webserver.

Comment: Thank you @Oded, I show that changes were done, nice job +1